# Firefox: Window similar to Chrome extension window

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Sample Chrome extension opens a window after pressing its corresponding button in the upper-right corner of the browser (near the menu list opener). How to open such window for Firefox extension (using jpm preferably).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the same functionality in a firefox add-on using [toggle buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_toggle). Specifically take a look at [attaching panels to buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_toggle#Attaching_panels_to_buttons).

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to open a new window when the button of your extension is pressed is the following:

**main.js**:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var { ActionButton } = require("sdk/ui/button/action");

var button = ActionButton({
    id: "my-button",
    label: "my button",
    icon: {
      "16": "./icon-16.png",
      "32": "./icon-32.png",
      "64": "./icon-64.png"
    },
    onClick: handler
});

function handler() {
    tabs.open("https://developer.mozilla.org");
}
```

Make sure that the icons of your extension should be in the `data` folder.

Look at mozilla developers documentation for more information:

- [Buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action)
- [Tabs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs)